# SQL 2008 : How can i see Temptable in DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made one temp table in my database.
My question is "How can i see my temp table in database ?"
Is it physically allocated ?

Comment: What are you asking? How to find out the location of the data pages on disc for the `#temp` table and see the row storage graphically?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table prefaced with a pound sign, it gets created in your tempdb database. Once the procedure calling it is over, it is automatically dropped.

create table #notforlong (id int,catname varchar(20))

It now exists in  tempdb

You could find it in sysobjects where name like '#notforlong%'.  However, since it goes away outside your proc anyway, I'm not sure it's helpful to refer to it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is completely unclear.

What do you mean by "seeing the table graphically"?

Here's an answer for one interpretation of it as you also mention physical allocation (Assumes: SQL Server 2008)

```
CREATE TABLE #foo
(
bar int,
baz nchar(100)
)

insert into #foo values (1, REPLICATE('A',100))

select sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) AS RID, bar, baz
FROM #foo /*Returned 1:121:0 for me*/
```

Then look at that page in SQL Internals Viewer

[image: Screenshot]